# How to document that a name of a variable can be different in another taxonomy?

Tags: discord, jsdoc, taxonomy, facebook-messenger, variable-names

For example, the taxonomies for community chat in Discord and Messenger are different, but they serve the same functionality:

| Discord | Messenger |
| --- | --- |
| Server | Community |
| Text Channel/Forum Channel | Community Chat |
| Channel Thread/Forum Post | Sidechat |

In my code I want to use the taxonomy of Discord to have better readability experience. Is there a tag to document that the variable names can be different in another taxonomy?

```js
/**
 * @tagForFunctionName doStuff - This can work on both Discord servers or Messenger community
 * @tagForVariableName server, servers - In Discord it's called server. In Messenger it's call community
 * @tagForVariableName channel, channels - In Discord it's called channel. In Messenger it's call community chat
 * @tagForVariableName thread, threads - In Discord it's called thread or topic. In Messenger it's call sidechat
 */
function doStuff(){
    const server = ...
    const servers = ...
    const channel = ...
    const channels = ...
    const thread = ...
    const threads = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:
"The [@see tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-see) allows you to refer to another symbol or resource that may be related to the one being documented." - [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-see)

```
    function doStuff() {
        /**
         * @see 'In Messenger its call community' https://path-to-community-docs-at-Messenger
         */
        const server = ...

        /**
         * @see 'In Messenger its call community chat' https://path-to-community-chat-docs-at-Messenger
         */
        const channel = ...

        /**
         * @see 'In Messenger its call sidechat' https://path-to-topic-documentation-at-Messenger
         */
        const thread = ...
    }
```

Comment: Which version is better? Can you explain the roles of the tags? The documentation seems to be terse

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag @context tag from [json linked data](https://json-ld.org/) . Then in the linked document (inside the comments or separate document) define the alternative identifier names using [Json linked data](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context).

```
/**
 * This function does 1, 2, 3, 4
 * 
 * @see 'JSON-LD the context' https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context
 * @context: {
 *    doStuff: "https://path-to-doStuff-documentation-at-Messenger",
 *    server: "https://path-to-community-docs-at-Messenger",
 *    channel: "https://path-to-community-chat-docs-at-Messenger",
 *    thread: "https://path-to-topic-documentation-at-Messenger"
 * }
 */
function doStuff() {
    const server = ...
    const channel = ...
    const thread = ...
}
```

Comment: does that mean JSDoc doesn't support this?

Comment: no. But inside the function above each variable. Try:
    @see 'In Messenger it's call community' https://path-to-community-docs-at-Messenger
const server = ,,,,